# Missing "Add Watch" context menu when right clicking on variable in VS2017 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

As the title says, there is no "Add Watch" context menu when right clicking on variable in VS2017 Community when debugging.

Please see screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I have updated the screenshot and it is in debug mode

Comment: You can only add a watch while running the app.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot. It is in debug mode

Comment: Your app is not paused .. does it work if you pause the running of your app

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not in debug mode. Start you application in debug mode and it will show up.

**EDIT:**

You must have hit a breakpoint to add a watch. The whole point of a watch is to be able to see the value change as you step through your code.

Comment: Ha I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To see the `Add Watch` or `QuickWatch`, you have to first start the debug application.